# Changing the input value after ajax response with jQuery not working well

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

On my WordPress web site I want to change the search input value after AJAX response.
After the RESPONSE when I right click  inspect element  the value of input is changed, but in the browser the value is same. I don't understand why, I will paste my code below.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {





const form = $('#posts-filter')

form.submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var input=$('#post-search-input').val();
    console.log(input);

    if(input.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null)
    {
     

      /*AJAX*/

      var endpoint="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
                                        var formdata=new FormData;                                      
formdata.append('action','enquiry2');
formdata.append('player_id',input);

$.ajax(endpoint,{
    type:'POST',
    data:formdata,
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
    
    success:function(res)
    
    {

          console.log(res);
        
            $('#post-search-input').attr('value',res); 

    

    
    /*   setTimeout(() => {
        e.currentTarget.submit();   
       }, 3000);  */

    }
})

    }
    if(input.match(/^[0-9]+$/) == null)
    {
        e.currentTarget.submit();
    }
});

});
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmEmo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line:

```
 $('#post-search-input').attr('value',res);
```

has to be:

```
$('#post-search-input').val(res);
```

if you want to chenge the value of a form-element you schould use $('.xxx')**.val('myValue')**